# How can I add own theme template for custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have some post type, but now I need to add certain templates like in pages section.

```
function products_init() {
  $args = array(
    'label' => 'Products',
    'capability_type' => 'page',
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-cart',
    'taxonomies' => array('category'),
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'products'),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'menu_position'       => 4,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes')
  );
  register_post_type('products', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'products_init');
```

Comment: Are you asking how to create template files or how to add custom fields to a post type (and display them in the creating/editing screen)?

Comment: Now, I now how to create template files, but they are not displaying when I trying to add new custom post type post.

Comment: As in - after you create a new post, you can't view it on the website when you go to the post's URL?

Comment: Yes, I am getting 404 error page

Comment: Could you paste the code where you are creating the post type, into your question?

Comment: I added all....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates) mentioned, you need to add two files to display custom post type.

```
archive-{post_type}.php
single-{post_type}.php
```

If you got a 404 error, you could try to call [`flush_rewrite_rules()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) in functions.php and refresh your page. If everything is ok, remove `flush_rewrite_rules`() immediately.

Otherwise you could flush reweire rules from dashboard -> Settings->Permalink page. Click on save button and then check if you can see the page. Save permalink settings will also call `flush_rewrite_rules`().